# What is Knowledge Base in Ubuntu Advantage support package?

Tags: canonical, ubuntu-advantage

In Ubuntu Advantage support package, paid commercial service provided by Canonical, one of the mentioned features is `The Canonical Knowledge Base` and official description is:

#### Technical library

> Exclusive to Ubuntu Advantage subscribers, the Canonical Knowledge
> Base is an online library of articles on technical issues including
> security, migration and networking.

What is it exactly? Can anybody with access to this Knowledge Base please explain and describe it with detail, how it works, mention how is it better from official documentation, what features it has and possibly provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [link](http://fleten.net/uploads/Ubuntu_Advantage%20Service%20Guide.pdf), this will help you.

Find the details from the above link

Knowledge Base

Ubuntu Advantage customers have exclusive access to the Canonical Knowledge Base. This gives you access to technical articles written and audited by Canonical’s GSS senior engineers. The database provides you with a library of technical articles to solve common issues immediately without having to log a support case.

Key benefits

Immediacy

The Knowledge Base helps you find solutions to your problems faster by giving you a central repository and a single reference point for tried-and-tested solutions to common issues. Solution categories include technical articles on security, migration and networking.

Best practices

Our Knowledge Base and training courses help you reduce potential issues so you can run your Ubuntu systems according to best practices. We provide easy-to-follow guidelines to support you in the process of configuring and implementing specific workloads on Ubuntu.

Skills transfer

Quickly gain the skills necessary to confidently use and manage Ubuntu in your business so that you can see a quick return on your investment. The Ubuntu Certified Professional course will help you efficiently install and configure Ubuntu systems, maintain system security and configure network connectivity and key network services.

Support systems

When you experience an issue, your first course of action should be to consult the Knowledge Base through the support portal. The Knowledge Base contains a range of documentation detailing issues and solutions that have been experienced by other users.

If there is no appropriate solution, you can either enter the problem through the support portal ticketing system, or you can telephone GSS directly. Severity level 1 and level 2 issues should be reported by phone.

Support Tier 1

Initial calls are handled by Tier 1 engineers who have been trained to handle basic configuration or usage issues. The engineer’s first task is to verify the nature of the issue and the severity level of the problem. Having done so, they will work with you to undertake basic debugging and deliver an appropriate resolution. 
If the problem is beyond this tier’s capability, it is escalated to the second tier.

Support Tier 2

Tier 2 engineers have extensive Ubuntu experience and may be specialists in a particular domain of knowledge. Aside from escalated issues, this tier deals with complex problems where there are a range of subsystems involved. The engineer will work to recreate a complex problem and isolate it into a repeatable test case. In general, issues that involve advanced configuration are resolved at this level. Any resolved issue is then added to the Knowledge Base so you and other users will be able to resolve it in the future.

Support Tier 3

An issue that moves through to the Tier 3 group has been isolated to a repeatable test case. The third tier works on any code changes that are necessary to resolve the problem for you. This generally involves developing and testing a custom patch for you and delivering this as a customer package. If this is successful, the engineer will work with the distribution developers to integrate the package into future releases of Ubuntu.

[image]

Hope this might be useful.

Comment: @Karlos thank you for great link, very happy you included it here, please read `how to answer` link http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer especially `Provide context for links` part and edit your answer please so I can award you the bounty.